# Is the Karhunen–Loève transform optimal only for Gaussian data?

Tags: correlation, covariance-matrix

I read in [1, Sec. I] that "the Karhunen–Loève transform is the best to
decorrelate discrete jointly gaussian random variables". Is that true? Is Gaussianity really required for optimality? If this is the case, why? I am confused because KLT is based on the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix of the data, so it seems that as long as the covariance is defined KLT should be optimal.

[1] Galli, Luca, and Saverio Salzo. "Lossless hyperspectral compression using KLT." IGARSS 2004. 2004 IEEE International Geoscience and Remote Sensing Symposium. Vol. 1. IEEE, 2004.

Comment: please cite paper

Comment: Hi:This is a guess ( because I'm not familiar with that transform )  but it may be because the covariance matrix (along with the mean) is all that is needed to fully identify the gaussian joint likelihood. The same cannot be said  for other multivariate  distributions.